# lshw not reporting memory information correctly

Tags: ubuntu, memory, hardware-detection

We are working a project where we will be receiving 50+ laptops on a regular basis and we need to get hardware information from them. During some test runs we found some strange results.  On a Dell Latitude e6400 when running lshw, we see this result:

```
*-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: NT2GTT64U88B0UN-3C
         vendor: Nanya Technology
         physical id: 0
         serial: C54E0B27
         slot: DIMM_A
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: NL825642120HF-D53M
         vendor: 7F7F7F1600000000
         physical id: 1
         serial: 00000000
         slot: DIMM_B
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

Bank 0 is correct, but bank 1 obviously is not.  When we looked at the physical card on the machine, we can confirm that the info for bank 1 is incorrect as we would like to have the product, vendor and serial number as well as the size.  We tried cleaning the contacts and re-seating the memory but to no avail.  We have seen this on both Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10

Has anyone seen anything like this before or have any suggestions?

Comment: Which information in bank 1 do you think is incorrect? The vendor and serial number? It may be that the RAM is not correctly providing that information to your computer. The product information looks accurate.

Comment: The serial number is for sure wrong, the rest is either correct or inconsequential.  We have found a way to work around this problem, but our records are more complete with the serial numbers of each ram card.

Comment: Are you sure this information is correct in the SPD? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) My hypothesis is that it is not, and if so, there's nothing Linux can do about it.

Answer (score 5):

It may be related to SPD revision version 1.2 or shust a non-standard/buggy module. If your are trying with last version of `lshw` then try:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

Or a root shell:

```
apt-get install lm-sensors  # Install lm_sensors
sensors-detect  # Configure lm_sensors
```

Then add necessary modules to /etc/modules and reboot or

```
modprobe <necessary_module>
```

Install i2c-tools (heterogeneous set of I2C tools for Linux). The SPD EEPROM is accessed using SMBus, a variant of the I²C protocol.

```
apt-get install i2c-tools
modprobe eeprom # Load the eeprom kernel module
```

Finally, grab memory information with `decode-dimms`.